# How to move from Child to Parent in a tree structure?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, tree, parent-child

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *child;
    node *sibling
};
```

I want to have a loop that moves from child to parent. If the root of a tree has 5 children then starts from last child to root. meaning that the loop should move in a reverse way.

In fact, it could be easy if I have an array of children, but what if I just have a child parent relationship, in that case, each child has a parent, So is it possible that I go from child to parents until I get to root.

Comment: If you want to go from a child to a parent, you need a pointer in the node that points you back to the parent. Otherwise, you can go only from root to the node, but not back.

Comment: In general such a tree node should have parent, child, next, previous. The tree itself should always know the root. Also you have tagged visual-c++, maybe you are looking for `SendMessage TVM_GETNEXTITEM TVGN_ROOT`

Comment: I get the idea, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a parent pointer to move directly from child to parent in a loop.
I find this works.

```
struct node{
    int value;
    node * parent;
    node ** childArray;
    int NumberOfChildren;
}
```

You set parent to null on the root node, and set the childArray pointer to null on the leaf (final) node.

When you want to move through the tree you use a node*.

e.g.

```
node * PCurrentNode = &MyNode;
PCurrentNode = MyNode->Parent;//Move Up
PCurrentNode = MyNode->ChildNodes[5]//Move to the 5th child node
```

You can avoid using parent pointers if you start at the root node and recurse down as you simply recurse up to get to the parent node.

Comment: So, I have to create an array of childs as you suggested, same what I was thinking. Thanks.